# Название выдвижной части стола

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется эта выдвижная часть столика?

Comment: Выдвижная полка для клавиатуры, которой нет. Для вас она — дополнительная многоцелевая.

Answer (score 3):

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
1. [ПО́ЛКА](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Polka-30649.html)
1. Доска, горизонтально укреплённая на стене, в стене или в шкафу, для предметов домашнего обихода, книг и т. п. ***Выдвижная полка.*** Книжная, кухонная полка. Полка этажерки. Полка в буфете. Полка для цветов, для обуви. Расставить на полке специи. Повесить в ванной полку. Разложить бельё по полкам. Произведение с полки (долго пролежавшее, не публиковавшееся или не пускавшееся в прокат).

Я думаю, что это выдвижная **полка** (для клавиатуры).